# Plot means over grouped boxplot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, boxplot

I am using multiple_boxplot function to generate grouped boxplots:
http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47233-multiple-boxplot-m

However, instead of medians I want to plot means. First I tried general method:

```
plot([mean(x)],'dg');
```

But it did not work. I tried to extract the means and then plot them but that also is not working.

```
m=[];
for i=1:max(group) 
idx=find(group==i);
m=[m nanmean(x(idx))];
end

boxplot(x,group, 'positions', positions);hold on 
plot([m],'dg')
```

What am I doing wrong? And how to plot the means with each boxplot? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

In the function `multiple_boxplot` change line 48 to:

```
B = boxplot(x,group, 'positions', positions);
```

and change the header of the function to:

```
B = multiple_boxplot(data...
```

and save the function file.

This won't change anything in how the function works but will let you obtain a handle to the boxplot (`B`).

Then in your code, create the boxplot as before, but with the output argument `B`:

```
B = multiple_boxplot(data...);
```

And add the following lines:

```
% compute the mean by group:
M = cellfun(@mean,data);
% convert it to pairs of Y values:
M = mat2cell(repmat(M(:),1,2),ones(size(M,1),1),2);
% change the medians to means:
set(B(6,:),{'YData'},M)
```